# Disproving the converse of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: group-theory

In this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) of wikipedia there is a disproving of the converse of Lagrange's theorem. I would like to see a more simple (or short) disproving of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: You mean a more simple disproof of *the converse of* Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: The counter-example in the Wikipedia article is the simplest possible. It would be much better if you tried to explain what you don't understand about that counter-example.

Comment: You will need a group that is not abelian, and of order at least $12.$ The answer in the Wikipedia, $A_4,$ is the smallest example you'll find. It's tedious proving that the subgroup of order $6$ doesn't exist, I agree.

Comment: That proof is pretty simple...you're going to need a non-abelian group.  Along the same lines you might note that $|A_5|=30$ but $A_5$ is simple, so it can't have a subgroup of index $2$ (hence there can be no subgroup of order $15$).  Not sure that's any simpler though.

Comment: @lulu You mean $|A_5|=60$, so it has no subgroups of order $30$. And I think this is an easier example because the explanation why there is no such subgroup is shorter. (of course if OP knows the non trivial theorem that $A_5$ is simple)

Comment: @Mark  Absolutely.  I got carried away dividing by $2$.  But, yes...this argument depends on knowing that $A_5$ is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the following proof:

Let $G$ be a finite group, $N \subset G$ a normal subgroup and $g \in G$. Then we obviously have that $\text{ord}(\overline{g})$ is a divisor of $\text{ord}(g)$, where $\overline{g}$ is the image of $g$ under the quotient map $G \rightarrow G/N$. Now assume that $[G:N] = 2$ and that $\text{ord}(g)$ has odd order. Then we get $\text{ord}(\overline{g}) = 1$ by Lagrange's theorem, such that $g \in N$. We just showed that every element of odd order needs to be in $N$. Therefore no group having more than $50$% elements of odd order can have a subgroup of index $2$. Since $A_4$ has $9$ elements of odd order it cannot have a subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: +1: That's nice and interesting: your answer uses the useful fact that subgroups of index 2 are normal, mine use the useful fact that we know what the groups of order 6 are: both our answers are more informative than the rather ad hoc proof in Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes! Totally agree.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is more short and can give a method for others cases.

Comment: Exactly. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: I agree that the Wikipedia proof that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$ is a bit convoluted. An alternative proof is to note that there are only two groups of order 6: the cyclic group $C_6$ and the dihedral group $D_3$. $A_4$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $C_6$ because it contains no element of order $6$. It has no subgroup isomorphic to $D_3$ because it has no elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that $\sigma^3 = \sigma$, $\tau^2 = \tau$ and $\tau\sigma\tau = \sigma^{-1}$. The calculations for the last part aren't too tedious, because you can assume w.l.o.g, that $\sigma = (1\,2\,3)$ and there are only three values of $\tau$ to try.

Comment: Actually never thought about proving the non-existence in that way - quite interesting.